# Android studio incompatible types required java.lang.String found java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, string

After updating my Android Studio and Java, I get the above error on a simple statement like:

```
String s = "";
```

It seems like Android Studio cant find my Java.

I use `Gradle` (from inside Android Studio) to build my project, on a `Windows 7(64bit)`.

I also get this error:

```
  @Override, not applicable to method
```

on my methods using:  `@Override`

You can check out the project on [Github](https://github.com/puppetmasterVALBY/GametemplateAndEngine), it works on my other computers, but not my home computer.

Can anyone please help me

Comment: Check if android studio can find the JDK ,click settings, project settings I think.

Comment: Android Studio do find the jdk, it seems more like it finds two, because of the error I get.

Comment: Point to to the correct Directory, what Operating System are you on ?

Comment: As mentioned, Windows 7. I have setup environment variables(JAVA_HOME), pointing to the same jdk as in Android studio

Comment: There is also a project specific jdk setting , try changing that under project settings , I had this issue too

Comment: That one points to the same directory as JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 14):

I know this is old but I got the same problem after my machine crashed while I was using Android Studio. The solution is quite simple, head to

```
File > Invalidate Caches & Restart
```

Your IDE will restart and your JAVA environment will be properly functional again.